# Seguridad deploy API Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, servidor, seguridad

Tengo una app hecha en Laravel solamente para consumir en REST pero como hago para que no quede público archivos y rutas sensibles como /storage o composer.json hasta el .env?
Qué buenas practicas recomiendan, si .htaccess es buena idea o no, y también como quito public de la ruta?

Estoy aprendiendo sobre servidores y deploys, escucho consejos sobretodo de seguridad.

PD: Uso Elastic beanstalk para deploy

Answer (score 0):

Hola estoy casi seguro que storage y .env están disponibles para el público, Laravel viene con un archivo .htaccess configurado para proteger public, donde estás enviando tu código de producción servidor compartido / VPS.

Para deployar la única aplicación que tenemos en en PHP en el trabajo utilizamos gitlab CI/CD

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/laravel_with_gitlab_and_envoy/

En este post encontrarás buenas prácticas para enviar tu aplicación a producción sin problemas.

Comment: Uso ec2 de Amazon